# Map transformation to apply a new path on a list of strings which are urls

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of strings (newsFeeds) which are a links. Some of them have a path component and some of them not. My goal is to apply a custom path component only when a path component is present. My code is below.

How to write it in more Kotlin style?

```
newsRepository.getAllNewsFeeds().observeForever { newsFeeds ->

    listNewsFeedUrls = newsFeeds.mapNotNull { newsFeed ->

        if (newsFeed.newsfeedURL?.toUri()?.path.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            newsFeed.newsfeedURL + "/us/json/news"
        } else {
            newsFeed.newsfeedURL
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code already looks good. Don't decrease readability for the sake of making it more Kotlinish.

If you still want to see another way, take a look at this:

If you want to avoid redundancy you could map you list of `newsFeeds` to a list of `newsfeedURLs` right away. Additionally you can concatenate either a path or an empty string to avoid having to reference `url` twice.

```
newsFeeds.mapNotNull(NewsFeed::newsfeedURL).map { url ->

     url.toString() + if (url.toUri()?.path.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        "/us/json/news"
    } else {
        ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you've written it is already pretty Kotlinish. You can also use such functions as `filter`, `zip`, for example:

```
val result = newsFeeds.filter { it.newsfeedURL != null && it.newsfeedURL.toUri().path.isNullOrEmpty()}
            .map { "${it.newsfeedURL}/us/json/news" }
            .zip(newsFeeds.filter { it.newsfeedURL != null && !it.newsfeedURL.toUri().path.isNullOrEmpty() })
```